# Coupled differential equation with variable coefficients

Tags: differential-equations

Need suggestion to implement and solve this coupled differential equation in mathematica.

$\frac{\delta}{\delta t} F_{1}(x,t)=C_1(x,t)F_{1}(x,t)+C_2(x,t)F_{2}(x,t)$

$\frac{\delta}{\delta t} F_{2}(x,t)=C_3(x,t)F_{2}(x,t)+C_4(x,t)F_{1}(x,t)$

With the initial condition $F_{1}(x,0) = g(x)$ and $F_{2}(x,0) = 0$.

Comment: What have you tried?

Comment: @mikado Sorry for my extremely late reply..while I was experimenting in Fortran, I haven't got any success in Mathematica yet.